# SSL verification doesn't happen with curl cacert option

Tags: ssl, certificate, curl, ssl-certificate

This is my understanding of curl `--cacert` option :

We can make curl perform SSL verification against a custom truststore by providing a PEM file path to this option. It is mostly used when we are trying to establish a connection to a server with self-signed certificate which I tried and it definitely works as expected.

Now, out of curiosity I tried to connect to https://google.com with a custom cacert having only stackexchange.com certificate. My assumption was that it will fail, but the SSL handshake was successful.

Would like to know the reason behind it or my understanding of cacert option is wrong.

```
$ curl -v https://google.com --cacert "stackexchange.pem"
*   Trying 142.250.192.78:443...
* Connected to google.com (142.250.192.78) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: stackexchange.pem
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.google.com
*  start date: Mar 28 01:19:44 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 20 01:19:43 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "google.com" matched cert's "google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1C3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7f86dd012000)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: google.com
> user-agent: curl/7.77.0
> accept: */*
>
< HTTP/2 301
< location: https://www.google.com/
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Fri, 15 Apr 2022 09:47:01 GMT
< expires: Sun, 15 May 2022 09:47:01 GMT
< cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
< server: gws
< content-length: 220
< x-xss-protection: 0
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
<
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
```

*The question is how the SSL handshake is successful as my truststore doesn't trust google.com and it only contains stackexchange.com in it.*

Output of `curl -V`

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.77.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0) libcurl/7.77.0 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.42.0
Release-Date: 2021-05-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

I am on macOS Monterey v12.1